# django url issue online

Tags: python, django

Here is my problem: When I finished coding,I use`

```
python manage.py runserver 4444
```

The app worked just fine.
However, when I put it into Elastic Compute Service, it raises url issue(404)
I don't understand because it can works in my computer! Why it can't work when I put it online?

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://121.42.40.115/notebook/homepage
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^notebook/ ^/homepage/$ [name='homepage']
^notebook/ ^/homepage2/$ [name='homepage2']
^notebook/ ^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
^notebook/ ^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/delete/$ [name='delete']
^notebook/ ^edit/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='edit']
^notebook/ ^/post/$ [name='post']
^notebook/ ^subject(?P<id>\w+)/$ [name='show_subject']
^notebook/ ^/create_subject/$ [name='create_subject']
^notebook/ ^/login_result/$ [name='login_result']
^notebook/ ^$ [name='login']
^notebook/ ^login_result/$ [name='login_result']
^notebook/ ^login_out/$ [name='login_out']
^notebook/ ^log_up/$ [name='log_up']
^notebook/ ^register_done/$ [name='register_done']
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, notebook/homepage, didn't match any of these.
```

And here is my related code in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^/homepage/$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
url(r'^/homepage2/$', views.homepage2, name='homepage2'),
url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.delete, name='delete'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
url(r'^/post/$', views.post, name='post'),
# url(r'^category(?P<category>\w+)/$', views.show_category, name='show_category'),
url(r'^subject(?P<id>\w+)/$', views.show_subject, name='show_subject'),
url(r'^/create_subject/$', views.create_subject, name='create_subject'),
url(r'^/login_result/$', views.login_result, name='login_result'),
url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^login_result/$', views.login_result, name='login_result'),
url(r'^login_out/$', views.login_out, name='login_out'),
url(r'^log_up/$', views.log_up, name='log_up'),
url(r'^register_done/$', views.register_done, name='register_done'),
# url(r'/upload_image/$', views.upload_image, name='upload_image'),
]
```

Why did this happen? It doesn't make any sense to me. Please help me solve it.

Comment: I see there is an extra url of login_result view in it!

Comment: sorry,  it does not work at all by removing the / from ^/homepage/$

Comment: what do you think your patterns should be to match `/notebook/homepage` to `^notebook/ ^/homepage/$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading slashes from your url patterns

For example, it should be

```
url(r'^homepage/$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
```

instead of

```
url(r'^/homepage/$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
```

Note your url patterns have trailing slashes, so you should go to

```
http://example.com/notebook/homepage/
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/notebook/homepage
```

Usually this doesn't matter, and Django will redirect to the url with the trailing slash.